# PostgreSQL: How do you set a "counter" variable as an array index in a while loop statement?

Tags: postgresql, while-loop, plotly-dash, pgadmin

I am trying to implement a while loop that will create new table rows for each element in an array.

In the code below, `prc_knw` is a user-input expression that is structured as an array. I want to take each of the elements in `prc_knw` and separate them into new rows in my table `processknowledgeentry` where each row has the same `prc_id` taken from another table. Each time the statement loops, I want it to move to the next `prc_knw` array element, and I want the variable `counter` to indicate the index.

```
do $$

declare 
    counter integer := 1;
begin
    while counter <= (select array_length(prc_knw,1))  loop                            
        INSERT INTO processknowledgeentry (prc_id,knw_id, pke_delete_ind)
        VALUES ((SELECT prc_id FROM process
        WHERE prc_id = (SELECT MAX(p.prc_id) FROM process AS p)),prc_knw[counter], False);
        counter := counter + 1;
    end loop;
end$$;
```

I'm stuck on how to format `prc_knw[counter]`. The error I get is: *SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "[" LINE 14: ...ECT MAX(p.prc_id) FROM process AS p)),**ARRAY[1,2,3][counter]**,...*

I've tried formatting it like `prc_knw['%',counter]`, and the error I receive is: *IndexError: list index out of range* (because I'm building this app in Python Dash and it's connected to a database in pgAdmin 4).

Hope you can help, thank you! Also feel free to let me know if there is a better approach to this.

Comment: [Looping through arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY) in the Postgres manual - but I doubt you need a loop to begin with. And what is the purpose of the `select max(..)` - that looks like a really bad idea?  But something like `insert into processknowledgeentry (prc_id,knw_id, pke_delete_ind)  select (select max(p.prc_id) from process p), knw.id, false FROM unnest(prc_knw) as knw(id)`  might work

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name! Thank you so much for the reference and insight :D The ```select max(..)``` is meant to select the most recently generated ```prc_id``` from another table (since it's incremental) and pair it with the ```knw_id```s. Feel free to let me know what you think of this. Will try out your suggestion now :D

Comment: Hi, just an update, your suggestion worked really well! Thanks so much! @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: The `select max()` won't work correctly with concurrent transactions.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! I decided to use ```RETURNING prc_id``` instead :)